# Installing opencv 3.1.0 for python2.7 on kubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I try to install opencv for python2.7 on my ubuntu but nothing seem to work.
Whatever I do, I can't import cv2

I tryed to download the sources and cmake / make / make install. (as describe here http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html ). I have no error during the process. But when I launch python and try to import cv2 I have the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named cv2

I read a lot of stack overflow post with no luck so I figured I should ask myself

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issues. The make install did not put the cv2.so in the correct location.
I had to manually put it in my lib/python2.7/site-packages/